# Count and Group By Returning Different Sets - Halfway solved :/

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help?  My trouble is that people might have the same id or different and have different name spellings. If I group by id (which is not the primary key) I get a different amount of rows than if I group by ID and name. How do I just group by ID, while still having the ID and Name in the select?

```
Create Table Client(ID Int, Name Varchar(15))
Insert Into Client VALUES(11,'Batman'),(22,'Batman'),(33,'Robin'),(44,'Joker'),(44,'The Joker'),(33,'Robin')

Select Count(ID) From Client
Select * From Client
```

--This returns 4 rows as it should

```
Select Count (ID)
From Client
Group By ID
```

--This returns 5 rows because Joker and The Joker have different names, but the same ID.  I want to count by ID and not the name, since so many have typos.

```
Select Count (ID), [Name] , ID  
From Client
Group By ID, [Name]
```

How do I do this and have it work?

```
Select Count (ID), [Name] , ID  
From Client
Group By ID   --<< Always throws and error unless I include Name, which 
--returns too many rows.
```

It should return

```
Count   Name    ID
1       Batman  11
1       Batman  22
2       Joker   44   --<< Correct
2       Robin   33

And not
    Count   Name        ID
    1       Batman      11
    1       Batman      22
    2       Robin       33    
    1       Joker       44  --Wrong
    1       The Joker   44  --Wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

using `select count(*) from ClientLog` will tell you exactly how many records there are in your table. If your `ID` field is the primary key, then `select count(ID) from ClientLog` should return the same number.

Your first query is a little confusing, because you're grouping by ID but not displaying the ID. So you're likely getting a row for each record, where the row value is 1.

Your 2nd query is also a bit confusing, because there's no aggregation happening (since your `ID` field is unique).

What specifically are you trying to obtain in your query (if anything besides just how many records you have in your table)?

Comment: Thanks. I did narrow down the records so I cannot just do a select all. I wish it were that simple. There's some joins, too.  There may be multiple entries in this table per client, and I'm trying to sum them.  So I need something like 185A25 Batman 10   The ID is not the primary key.

Comment: `NULL`s might also be causing a problem, since they don't count in the COUNT function. So a `count(*)` would return all records in the table, but if any of the fields are `NULL`, you might be getting a lower number. Do you have records where either the `ID` or `Name` could be null?

Comment: I don't think there are any Nulls. There might be in some of the tables, but the ID and Name fields all have values, at least from what I can tell scrolling through that many records.  Thanks.